# PHP form validation submit problem

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I try to submit the form and I have not entered nothing in the year field I get `Incorrect year!` how can I still submit the form without having to enter a year. In other words leaving the year field blank and not getting a warning?

Here is the PHP code.

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/', $_POST['year'])) {
    $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['year']);
} else {
    $year = NULL;
}

if($year == NULL) {
    echo '<p class="error">Incorrect year!</p>';
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You need to check for `$year === NULL`. PHP can and will silently convert a null value to an empty string, so a blank $year can equal null. the === (contents AND type match) comparison operator solves that problem.

Comment: @Marc B, I tried this but for some reason I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/', $_POST['year'])) {
    $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['year']);
} else {
    $year = false;
}

if ($year === false) {
    echo '<p class="error">Incorrect year!</p>';
} else {
    //do something
}
```

OR (if you didn't set YEAR somewhere else)

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/', $_POST['year'])) {
    $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['year']);
}

if (!isset($year)) {
     echo '<p class="error">Incorrect year!</p>';
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: your second example some what works but know it allows for one character to be entered.

Comment: The problem is in your preg_match not the change I made.

Comment: I just tested and it looks working fine. Are you setting $year somewhere else?

Comment: But it now lets me add letters and it wont check to see if at least four numbers have been entered.

Comment: Post your whole code there is another issue which is hidden from the code you showed or change your IF to something like this - if (intval($_POST['year']) && strlen($_POST['year']) == 4) {

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/', $_POST['year'])) {
    $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['year']);
} else if(empty($_POST['year'])){
    $year = '';
} else {
    $year = null;
} 

if($year == NULL) {
    echo '<p class="error">Incorrect year!</p>';
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but this sounds like what you want.

Comment: if $year is set to an empty string then $year == null will evaluate to true. Change $year == null to $year === null

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can just take this part out and it will take the echo out allowing you to submit with the field being blank

```
if($year == NULL) {
    echo '<p class="error">Incorrect year!</p>';
} else {
    //do something
}
```

I wouldn't suggest allowing it to go blank into the database. Maybe you can just grab the default date on the server or a default value meaning the user didn't fill it out. This would take the error out but still leave something in the database field.

Comment: You've completely misunderstood the concept of validation. You don't fix the problem by removing the code altogether.